# how do i route to my .asmx file in asp.net 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

i have seen this question which explains how to add webService to my dnx project
[How to use soap web services in Asp.net Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28619860/how-to-use-soap-web-services-in-mvc-6-using-asp-net-5) but i can't seem to understand how to mapRoute to my asmx file or how to use WCF in the asp vNext,

what i have done:

1. tried to create a WCF service project, but the problem is that the project won't be on the DNX.
2. manually add asmx and cs.asmx files but i can't find how to serve them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, WCF is not supported in ASP.NET 5.

Comment: and is it possible to use it with dnx451?