# How to consume SOAP WebService with ASP.NET vNext?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I was playing with ASP.NET vNext, simulating real-life scenarios, and did not realize how to consume SOAP WebServices using CORE CLR.

Is it supported? Does anyone knows how to do it?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28413756/asp-net-5-add-wcf-service-reference/28423655#28423655