# Host wcf service dll in ASP.NET 5 (rc1) website

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, asp.net-core

I've got a full .net Framework wcf Service compiled as dll and want to host (and use) this in a ASP.NET 5 web site.

Now since ASP.NET 5 does not contain a web.config anymore the usual Hosting of wcf Services from older Versions of asp.net do not work anymore.

So how do I host (and use) a wcf service dll from ASP.NET 5?

Comment: Have you looked at this question and answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/28440491/745969

Comment: kewl, thanks - had not found that post, will have a look!