# WCF .NET Core - WsHttpBinding Configuration project.json

Tags: wcf, asp.net-core-1.0

How do I configure wsHttpBinding with .NET core, Should I configure in Project.json file ? Before .NET Core the configuration is like below

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="IService_Endpoint">
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://serviceURL/Service.svc"
      binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="IService_Endpoint"
      contract="IService" name="IService_Endpoint" />
</client>
```

I found an article which works looks like I am looking for but its BasicHttpBinding, I need wsHttpBinding.

```
ChannelFactory<IGetPeopleService> factory = null;  
IGetPeopleService serviceProxy = null;  
Binding binding = null;

binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.None);  
factory = new ChannelFactory<IGetPeopleService>(binding, new EndpointAddress("http://localhost/people.svc"));  
serviceProxy = factory.CreateChannel();

var result = serviceProxy.GetPeopleData(100);
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be as simple as the following:

```
ChannelFactory<IGetPeopleService> factory = null;  
IGetPeopleService serviceProxy = null;  
Binding binding = null;

binding = new WsHttpBinding(SecurityMode.None);  
factory = new ChannelFactory<IGetPeopleService>(binding, new EndpointAddress("http://localhost/people.svc"));  
serviceProxy = factory.CreateChannel();

var result = serviceProxy.GetPeopleData(100);
```

Baically, swap `BasicHttpBinding` for `WsHttpBinding`.

**ADDED Information**

Taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28440491/745969):

You need to add a reference to `System.ServiceModel` in your project.json, like this:

```
{
  "commands": {
      "run": "run"
  },
  "frameworks": {
      "dnx451": {
          "dependencies": {
              "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta2"
          },
          "frameworkAssemblies": {
              "System.ServiceModel": "4.0.0.0"
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Note this answer was for ASP.NET 5 Pre-Release.

Comment: Tim, Thanks for your response. I am unable to resolve WsHtppBinding with in same SystemModel assembly

Comment: @AnandPatel - Do you mean `WsHttpBinding` or `WsHtppBinding`? It should be `WsHttpBinding` per my example (two "t", not two "p").

Comment: Sorry for Type. yes WsHttpBinding

Comment: Added a snippet regarding the project.json file.

Comment: The System.ServiceModel for .NET core does not have a WsHttpBidning

Comment: @Jonny The reference in the above is to .NET standard, not core.  System.ServiceModel 4.0.0.0 does indeed have WsHttpBinding.

Comment: @Tim yes, but the question asked was for .NET Core - not .NET Framework.

Comment: And the answer, IMO, was for .NET Core.   OP asked "How do I configure wsHttpBinding with .NET core", and my answer showed one way of doing it in .NET Core.

Comment: I could not find WsHttpBinding in .Net standard too!