# Unable to consume WCF WSHttpBinding in .net core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'am trying to move my project from .net to .net core. I  was initially using WCF WSHttpBinding service in .net but I'am unable to consume the same in .net core. I tried using BasicHttpBinding to connect with WsHttpBinding on the client side, but it throws an error saying the Bindings should match on both client and server side.

Suggest how to implement WSHttpBinding on .Net Core without modifying 
WSHttpBindings on the client side.?

Comment: Something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38209824/wcf-net-core-wshttpbinding-configuration-project-json ???

Answer (score 7):

I was able to make it work using a custom binding.  There are also https, text, and binary binding elements that can be configured.

```
var binding = new CustomBinding
{
    Elements = { new HttpTransportBindingElement //or HttpsTransportBindingElement for https:
    {
        MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue,
        MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue
    }}
};
```

Comment: I confirm what this one works for me. I porting WCF client from 4.7 framework to core 2.2

Comment: Dang, that didn't work for me. I got this: {"The action http://tempuri.org/XXXService/GetXXXList is not supported by this endpoint. Only WS-ReliableMessaging February 2005 messages are processed by this endpoint."}

Comment: @AussieJoe, I'm a little late to the party but the response looks like it did work and the service is telling you that you are trying to call a non-existing endpoint.

Answer (score 4):

WCF WSHttpBinding is not support yet in .net core 2.1.
Here are the list of supported bindings in .Net core

- BasicHttpBinding
- CustomBinding
- NetHttpBinding
- NetTcpBinding

read more about supported features [click here](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/blob/master/release-notes/SupportedFeatures-v2.1.0.md)

Comment: Should the bindings be same on both client and server side..? Because if Iam trying to connect using BasicHttpBinding or NetHttpBinding to client side which is WSHttpBinding in .net core it throws an exception "Client and server bindings are mismathced".

Answer (score 4):

I used WSHttpBinding on full framework. After migration to .net core 2.2 I faced with same problem.

Later I found that BasicHttpsBinding (it is https, not http) perfectly fits my need. I simple replaced WSHttpBinding with BasicHttpsBinding and all works fine (on windows and on linux).

Comment: BasicHttpsBinding didn't work for me, but CustomBinding ([suggested by Nicholas J. Markkula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52182419/unable-to-consume-wcf-wshttpbinding-in-net-core/56762425#56762425) ) works.

Comment: Just god bless you.
EDIT: everyone you guys whoever I found in internet after this hours of struggling and whose comments and answers helped me to consume crappy .Net Framework 4.0 wcf service in net core 2.1 wep API

Answer (score 1):

This is a more complete answer and may help someone who is trying to call a SOAP service endpoint using .NET Core (.NET Core 2.2) and is struggling to get it working.

For the answer I'm assuming you've already added a Connected Service. If not, please refer to this [Microsoft Article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide)

The example below is using a `BasicHttpBinding` with an `Ntlm` Credential Type (DOMAIN\Username):

```
public async Task<string> ImportSalesOrder(string jsonString)
{
    var binding = new BasicHttpsBinding();
    binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Ntlm;

    var endpoint = new EndpointAddress(_appConfig["endpoint"]);

    var client = new eCommIntegrationMgt_PortClient(binding, endpoint);

    client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = _appConfig["usernam"];
    client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = _appConfig["password"];

    try
    {
        var result = await client.ImportSalesOrderAsync(jsonString);

        return result.return_value;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

`_appConfig` is a global variable, which is made available via DI (Dependency Injection). You can replace them with hard-coded values if you're not making use of DI. The `catch` is redundant here, but you can add your custom error handling/logging.

`eCommIntegrationMgt_PortClient` is the client i.e. the Service object where all our endpoints exist.

Answer (score 1):

Here is snippet what I used

```
        var binding = GetCustomBinding();

        private Binding GetCustomBinding()
        {
            CustomBinding result = new CustomBinding();
            TextMessageEncodingBindingElement textBindingElement = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement();
            result.Elements.Add(textBindingElement);
            HttpsTransportBindingElement httpsBindingElement = new HttpsTransportBindingElement
            {
                AllowCookies = true,
                MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue,
                MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue,
                AuthenticationScheme = System.Net.AuthenticationSchemes.Negotiate
            };
            result.Elements.Add(httpsBindingElement);
            return result;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

.Net Core not support WsHttpBinding yet .
You can try this.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/WsSecurityCore/

You can get the response as XmlNodeList or Xml full string and convert to response your class use XmlSerializer.