# Unable to consume WCF WebHttpBinding in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, wcf, wcf-binding

I am trying to move my project from .NET to .NET Core.

I tried using `BasicHttpBinding` and `CustomBinding` to connect with my WCF service on the client side, but this throws an error.

Suggest how to implement `WebHttpBinding` on .NET Core?

Comment: Did you check this answers : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52182419/unable-to-consume-wcf-wshttpbinding-in-net-core ?

Comment: Maybe you can take a look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56462686/alter-a-wcf-service-for-compatibility-with-both-net-framework-net-core-calle).It's for Compatibility with both .NET Framework & .NET Core Callers.