# Soap header was not understood

Tags: soap, .net-core, sabre

Remote wcf service needs a custom header 'MessageHeader' in the envelope. I'm adding this header, but processing response returns this error:

> 'The header 'MessageHeader' from the namespace
>   'http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader' was not understood by
>   the recipient of this message, causing the message to not be
>   processed. This error typically indicates that the sender of this
>   message has enabled a communication protocol that the receiver cannot
>   process. Please ensure that the configuration of the client's binding
>   is consistent with the service's binding.'

In classic .net recommend change BasicHttpBinding on WsHttpBinding, but core doesn't support it. Can anybody give me some advices?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WCF .NET Core - WsHttpBinding Configuration project.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38209824/wcf-net-core-wshttpbinding-configuration-project-json)

Comment: core doesn't support WsHttpBinding

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a namespace issue. Please post your RQ + RS and identify what API you are using.