# AspNet Core Consuming WebService (VS2015)

Tags: soap, asp.net-core, wsdl, client

In my AspNet Core project I need to consume a SOAP/WSDL WebService. I am using VS2015 and have made a non-aspnet core project to test the webservice (went fine), but with AspNet Core, I cannot seem to find a way to make this happen. It looks like SOAP webservice isn't supported (yet?) but if that is the case, is there a different way to consume a soap webservice?

I am already using the net461 framework so I can use the normal .NET libraries, but VS2015 doesn't expose the “Add Service Reference” menu option.

Answer (score 0):

Find this similar question. I have not implemented/verified/tested it but hopefully yo can find some guidance. The sample is using the prior version of AspNet Core (AspNet 5)

[ASP.NET 5 add WCF service reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28413756/asp-net-5-add-wcf-service-reference/28440491#28440491)

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide
See if this helps. In VS 2017, I am able to add the service reference from connected services in a .net core project. You might need to install "WCF Service Reference Provider" Extension.